# How to display images in hterm + screen

Tags: ssh, terminal, gnu-screen

I am using the SSH extension on CrOS to connect to another machine. I would like to use the [hterm-show-file](https://chromium.googlesource.com/apps/libapps/+/master/hterm/etc/hterm-show-file.sh) script to display images directly in the terminal.  This works fine in a normal shell, but when I run the command inside a screen session, instead I just get the base64 text printed to my terminal.

I suspect the problem lies either in terminal settings or the escape codes used.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in the latest version of `hterm-show-file`.